# Combining iterrows of pandas with os.walk given I have a lot of directories

Tags: python, file-system, pandas

I have the following code snippet:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['MSI Status'] == 'MSS':
        print(row['Patient ID'])
        
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for dirname in dirnames:
                joined_path = os.path.join(path, dirname)
                if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
                    shutil.copytree(joined_path, os.path.join('/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status/MSS', dirname))
    if row['MSI Status'] == 'MSI-H':
        print(row['Patient ID'])
        
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for dirname in dirnames:
                joined_path = os.path.join(path, dirname)
                if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
                    shutil.copytree(joined_path, os.path.join('/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status/MSI-H', dirname))
```

I only have 100 rows in my df but I have many directories in my os.walk. I understand my code is not written well or not efficient and is slow and I hope to get some feedback.

Comment: What does the file structure look like?

Answer (score 5):

- First off, you seem to have a typo: `os.path.join(path, dirname)` should almost certainly be `os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)`. The only way I could see this not causing problems is if all the directories you want to copy are immediate children of `path` - and in that case you don't want [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) at all, but should instead use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir). But going forward I'll assume that [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is in fact needed here
- Since the target directory's name matches the `MSI Status` field, and those two loops are otherwise identical, it'd be easy to merge those two loops into a single one, ending with something like:

  ```py
  destination = os.path.join("/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status", row["MSI Status"], dirname)
  shutil.copytree(joined_path, destination)
  ```
- If those are the only two statuses that are possible, you'd be able to get rid of the `if`s entirely. If not, you can still simplify it to something akin to `if row['MSI Status'] in {'MSI-H', 'MSS'}:`
- Back to [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) issues, once you've found a directory to copy, will you ever need to copy any subdirectory of that directory? For example, for a patient with ID `somebody`, would you want/need to copy *both* `./somebody/` and `./somebody/appointment_history/somebody_2020-12-13` independently? If not, you should modify the `dirnames` list while iterating to avoid descending into the directories you've already copied - which could perhaps look like this:

  ```py
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
      remaining = []

      for dirname in dirnames:
          if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
              source = os.path.join(path, dirname)
              destination = os.path.join('/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status', row['MSI Status'], dirname)
          else:
              remaining.append(dirname)

      dirnames[:] = remaining # Note the use of [:] to update in-place
  ```
- Finally, pandas' [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) is almost certainly faster than `os.walk`, so if we're going to do one of those multiple times, it might be best to let that be the [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). You might save time by turning your code inside-out like so:

  ```py
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
      remaining = []

      for index, row in df.iterrows():
          for dirname in dirnames:
              if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
                  source = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
                  destination = os.path.join(
                      '/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status',
                      row['MSI Status'],
                      dirname
                  )
                  shutil.copytree(source, destination)
              else:
                  remaining.append(dirname)

      dirnames[:] = remaining
  ```

Comment: If one were to combine our answers, your final bullet point would have the benefit of never walking down trees we've copied from ever. Gaining an even larger benefit than either of our answers would have standing alone. Nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

- You should make a function to contain the `os.walk(path)`. As both walks are almost identical, the difference is the destination directory.
- You're not walking correctly. If I have the file structure:

  ```
  ──.
    └─test
      └─test_nested
        └─test_file
  ```

  Then `os.walk` would walk down the tree, and `dirnames` would only contain the directory's name (`test`, `test_nested`).
  Ok, so lets say `row['Patient ID']` is `test_nested` then we're into the `if`.

  Now we're copying from `./test_nested` to `/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status/MSS/test_nested`.
  However the path to `test_nested` is actually `./test/test_nested`.

  You need to either:

  1. Include `dirpath` in the source and/or the destination path.
     `os.path.join(src, dirpath, dirname)`.
  2. Or assuming your code works correctly because `if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:` is never true in a subdirectory you need to break after the first iteration of the tree.
- > When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using [del](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) or slice assignment), and [walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform [walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes [walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) again.
  > [Python's `os.walk` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

  As such you should `dirnames.remove(dirname)` to prevent walking the path and duplicating copies.
  Or just wasting time.

```
def copy_tree__nested(src, dest):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
        for dirname in dirnames[:]:
            if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
                dirnames.remove(dirname)
                shutil.copytree(os.path.join(src, dirpath, dirname), os.path.join(dest, dirpath, dirname))


def copy_tree__tld(src, dest):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
        for dirname in dirnames:
            if row['Patient ID'] in dirname:
                shutil.copytree(os.path.join(src, dirname), os.path.join(dest, dirname))
        break


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['MSI Status'] == 'MSS':
        print(row['Patient ID'])
        copy_tree(path, '/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status/MSS')
    if row['MSI Status'] == 'MSI-H':
        print(row['Patient ID'])
        copy_tree(path, '/SeaExp/mona/MSS_Status/MSI-H')
```